# imagecopy in foreach loop x coords

Tags: php, loops, foreach, gdlib

I have this image function that I have a litte problem with

```
function BuildCustomBricks($myBricksAndRatios) {

        $img = imagecreate(890,502);
        imagealphablending($img, true);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);

        foreach ($this->shuffle_with_keys($myBricksAndRatios) as $key) {            

            $bricks_to_choose = rand(1,10);

            $cur = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/". $key."-".$bricks_to_choose.".png"); 
            imagealphablending($cur, true);
            imagesavealpha($cur, true);
            imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);

            imagedestroy($cur);
        }

        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($img);
    }
```

How can place each image in the foreach 100 pixels from the previous one?

```
next image in the loop:    
imagecopy($img, $cur, previous_x_coord+100, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
```

Comment: Why not do as you your self suggests, by setting a variable and add it with 100 every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store a variable which starts at zero and adds 100 at the end of every loop iteration:

```
    // Init at zero
    $coords = 0;
    foreach ($this->shuffle_with_keys($myBricksAndRatios) as $key) {            


        $bricks_to_choose = rand(1,10);

        $cur = imagecreatefrompng("/var/www/brickmixer/bricks/". $key."-".$bricks_to_choose.".png"); 
        imagealphablending($cur, true);
        imagesavealpha($cur, true);
        // Use the variable here
        imagecopy($img, $cur, $coords, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);

        imagedestroy($cur);

        // Add 100 at the end of the loop block
        $coords += 100;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is an option, but since you're using `foreach` instead of `while`, you could use the index of your array, too:

```
foreach ($this->shuffle_with_keys($myBricksAndRatios) as $factor => $key)
{
    //...Multiply index by 100: 0*100,1*100,2*100 etc...
    imagecopy($img, $cur, 100*$factor, 0, 0, 0, 125, 32);
    //...
}
```

It's a bit anal of me, but it doesn't require 2 extra lines of code, and no additional variable. Critics might say this code is *less maintainable*, in which case I'd say: 'Don't ninja-comment, then'

*Warning:*
As Michael pointed out, this code won't work with associative arrays for obvious reasons (`'First_Key'*100 === ?`)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: forgot to mention that, I'll add a warning.